# How to translate "Comfort the afflicted; afflict the comfortable?"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check, grammar-choice, ecclesiastical-latin

I am trying to translate the saying "Comfort the afflicted; afflict the comfortable" into Latin, but I don't actually know Latin, and I've run into a wall.

I think the verbs should be Present Active Imperative, either singular (*consolare, afflige*) or plural (*consolamini, affligite*). But I'm not 100% sure, because it seems like they could be Jussive mood instead (*consoleris/consolere/consolemini* and *affligas/affligatis*, if I understood correctly).

The objects are giving me a lot more trouble.
It seems "the afflicted," as a noun formed from a collective adjective based on a verb, should be the Perfect Passive Participle of *affligo* (*afflictus*), and should be plural. I'm less confident about the case (I think Accusative, right?). And I cannot find an explanation of how to determine the gender for this situation.
I wouldn't think "the comfortable" would be a participle. From my understanding it would be the adjective *commodus* used as a Substantive, but I can't figure out if that requires any change the word beyond the number/gender/case it would take. Then, as with "the afflicted," it seems like it would be plural and Accusative, but I don't know the gender.

Or I could be totally wrong about all of that.

(I've tagged ecclesiastical-latin because, although the phrase originates from journalism, it has since been applied to Christianity in some circles, and the words are certainly found in ecclesiastical writing.)

---

Since unfortunately, I did not get any responses to this question, I kept trying to work it out for myself. I've come to the conclusion that the 2nd person singular present active imperative verbs and accusative singular masculine/neuter adjectives are the correct form. I've also decided, based on the definitions given on Wiktionary, that *commodus* seems to be more appropriate for something that gives comfort than for someone who is enjoying comfort. The definitions for *securus* seem closer to the intent in English.

So my translation is: Consolare afflictum; afflige securum.

My new question is: does that make sense to everyone? Did I make any grammatical mistakes?

Comment: You are right when you say:"I think the verbs should be Present Active Imperative, either singular (consolare, afflige) or plural (consolamini, affligite)."

Comment: When a Latin verb is passive in form, but has an active meaning, it is called a deponent verb.They are tricky!

Comment: On the appropriateness of the [tag:ecclesiastical-latin] tag: While the phrase itself may have a secular origin, the sentiment seems to me to be quite biblical. See e.g. Ezekiel 34:16, in which God says, "I will seek the lost, and I will bring back the strayed, and I will bind up the injured, and I will strengthen the weak, but the fat and the strong I will destroy."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And if you wanted to say the **afflicted** and **comfortable** plural, instead of singular, you would have **Consolare afflictos ; afflige securos**.

Comment: Note that, because consolor is a deponent verb, consolare is not the actually the infinitive, as you claim, but the singular imperative; so Sven3B has used the correct form. However, I do think that your suggestion of a plural object for each verb would be a better choice than singular.

Comment: Quite right @cnread, I should have checked on consolor.

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason why one might go with the infinitive over the imperative?

Comment: @Sven3B [*consolor, -ari*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconsolor) is deponent, so the *-are* ending actually is imperative

Comment: Yes, consolor, consolari is a deponent verb which dropped certain part of the conjugation. I learnt it in Gregorian Chant for the Advent Antiphon: Consolamini. consolamini...Console, console your people! Passive form with active meaning!

Comment: Is there no way to duplicate the chiasmus? This translation is a bit feeble.